# Crear un PRIMARY KEY auto increment en ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, tablas, autoincremento

Cómo puedo crear un PRIMARY KEY auto increment en ORACLE versión 12.1? Digamos que tengo esta tabla

```
 CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_NAME (
    ID NUMBER(20,0),
    NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    SEX  CHAR(1)
    );
```

Y quiero que el campo ID tenga autoincremento

Comment: Versión de Oracle? Ve a [edit] e indícalo en la pregunta, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede evitarse la definición de una secuencia por separado, se puede hacer implícita en la definición del campo así:

```
 CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_NAME (
    ID NUMBER(20,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOT NULL ENABLE,
    NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    SEX  CHAR(1)
    );
```

Comment: Mira cómo queda tu aporte en el formato correcto. Te falta editar la pregunta e indicar para qué versión de Oracle funciona eso